# How can I add functions to a priority queue? (Is it even possible)

Tags: java, priority-queue

I know what is a priority queue and I know how to add strings/integers to it. But now I want to add functions to it. (If this makes sense??) . I am not ready to change the return type of any function.

I want to know how can I go about doing that? I made a raw type priority queue

```
PriorityQueue  prq = new PriorityQueue ();
prg.offer(login());
```

Now, I am not a coding genius, I am also learning. So I wanted to see if its possible. If it isn't possible are there any alternate solutions?

My pop() function will just run the function which got pop'd. Most of my functions are void.

An idea I got: Should I just insert string and do a switch statement depending on which string I pop()???

Comment: Java is not JavaScript, and functions ("methods" in Java) are not things you can assign to a variable (even an anonymous one) and then pass around. The programming model is rather difference, so you'd be well off to spend an hour reading the official [Java Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html). Doesn't take that long, and gives you a great boost in terms of understanding what Java can, can't, wants to and won't do.

Comment: Actually java can do what I asked, someone did answer my needs below (points to best answer) Thanks though :)

Comment: Actually, it can't, and the answer you got is about creating a new Runnable instance that is invoked to run rather differently from how methods are invoked. It might do what you want, but what you want to do is breaking quite a few Java best practices and conventions =)

Comment: Anyway, are you willing to throw away the return values if there are any?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are currently doing is putting the *return value* of the function in the queue. So the function executes and then the value that it produces is put into the queue. Instead you could have a queue of `Runnable`s and then call the `run()` method on them:

```
PriorityQueue<Runnable> queue = new PriorityQueue<Runnable>();
queue.offer( new Runnable() { public void run() { login(); } );

queue.remove().run();
```

Or, if using Java 8:

```
PriorityQueue<Runnable> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
queue.offer(() -> login(););
```

Comment: I like you and your idea! Let me try it! :D

Comment: You are correct! This is exactly what I wanted!! Loads of love thanks!! :D

Comment: @Indigo you should also be able to use lambdas instead of an anonymous class, but I do not know exactly how to do that in java. If someone else does, please edit the answer.

Comment: Not only does this break the conventions of using Runnable, it simply won't run, because `Runnable` does not implement `Comparable`, so you can't put it in a priority queue. I mean, you can `offer` it, but as soon as you try to `remove` or iterate over this queue, you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Correcting myself: not when you try to `remove`, but as soon as you `offer` a second element.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the function as an argument to priority queue (In java), but you can use return value of the function, as long as return type of the function matches the required argument.

The type of the argument in offer() is specified by generics. Here is code example.

```
public static int login(){

    return 0;
}

public static void main (String[] args){


    PriorityQueue<Integer>  prq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    prg.offer(login());
}
```

You can then change **Integer** to whatever is return type of your function login().

Comment: As stated in my question,  I am not ready to change the return type of any function.

Comment: You didn't specify what is the return type of your function. If it's void, the answer is "No you can't", if it's something else, then just change **Integer** to whatever the return type of your function is.

Comment: I did mention most of my functions are void in my question, thank you for your advice Ill look into it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to "Do something when Item is added to/removed from Queue", you can extend PriorityQueue. I can throw in some basic example.

Comment: @AlexanderTroshchenko he wants a queue of runnables that he can run when he pops them. See my answer.

Comment: She* wants a queue :P

Comment: @clcto Good insight skills :) However, Runnable is a separate thread, and when used anonymously may create some concurrent access problems. At this point it's important to understand the purpose, otherwise it's more of a band-aid than an answer.

Comment: @Indigo When using Runnables, be careful that every Runnable is running in parallel. So if you launch 10 Runnables, they are not waiting for previous one to end, and if all of them try to access one resource, your app can crash.

Comment: @AlexanderTroshchenko Actually, if you call the Runnable's `run()` method directly instead of using a Thread's `start()` to run it, it is not concurrent. Nevertheless, it shouldn't be done, exactly because anybody reading it would think it's concurrent.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Oh yeah, my bad... Been a while since I touched java. Still, if you want event to be triggered when something happens to a Queue, you should probably extend the Queue instead of adding Runnables...

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is possible to do something like this, but I would recommend thinking it through. And the implementation is a bit unwieldy.

First, you're working with a priority queue. This means that you want to receive the things that were added to it by order of their priority. A priority queue is an ordered collection. And in order to do that, the items you put inside it must be `Comparable`. This is why a priority queue of String or Integer work. Both of them are `Comparable` - if you have two Strings in the queue, it's easy to tell which comes first, as Strings have a natural order. Nevertheless it must be said that in real life, you normally don't assign things String priorities. A priority queue is supposed to represent which things are more urgent to deal with, and which are less so. So usually priorities are more likely to be implemented as some sort of number or Enum.

So in addition to putting a function in the queue, you also need to assign it a priority when you put it in the queue, and that will tell whoever is reading from the queue which functions it's more urgent to perform. He'll simply get them by order of priority.

So we need to define some sort of object that will encapsulate both a function and a priority:

```
public final class PrioritizedPerformer implements Comparable<PrioritizedPerformer> {

    /**
     * Actor interface. Represents a way to run a function.
     */
    public interface Actor {
        void perform();
    }

    /**
     * Available priorities
     */
    public enum Priority { URGENT, HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW };

    private Priority priority;
    private Actor actor;

    /**
     * Constructor that allows creating PrioritizedPerformer objects with a given priority and actor.
     * 
     * @param priority  Priority of this object when placed in a priority queue.
     * @param actor     Actor representing a function to be performed.
     */
    public PrioritizedPerformer(Priority priority, Actor actor) {

        // Don't allow null priorities, this will cause problems in priority queues.
        if ( priority == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must provide valid priority");
        }
        this.priority = priority;

        // Don't allow null actors. The action has to be available.
        if ( actor == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must provide valid actor");
        }
        this.actor = actor;
    }

    /* Allows prioritizing one PrioritizedPerformer over another.
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(PrioritizedPerformer o) {
        return priority.compareTo(o.priority);
    }

    /**
     * Perform whatever action the actor represents.
     */
    public void perform() {
        actor.perform();
    }
}
```

Now that we have that, we can put objects of this type into the priority queue:

```
    PriorityQueue<PrioritizedPerformer> queue = new PriorityQueue<PrioritizedPerformer>();

    queue.offer(new PrioritizedPerformer(
            PrioritizedPerformer.Priority.HIGH,
            new PrioritizedPerformer.Actor() {
                public void perform() {
                    login();
                }
            }));
    queue.offer(new PrioritizedPerformer(
            PrioritizedPerformer.Priority.LOW,
            new PrioritizedPerformer.Actor() {
                public void perform() {
                    quit();
                }
            }));
    queue.offer(new PrioritizedPerformer(
            PrioritizedPerformer.Priority.URGENT,
            new PrioritizedPerformer.Actor() {
                public void perform() {
                    returnThree();
                }
            }));
```

What we do here is construct each `PrioritizedPerformer` object with a given `Priority` and an anonymous `Actor` which performs the function we wanted it to perform.

Now we can run:

```
    queue.remove().perform();
```

This will remove the highest priority object from the queue, and run its `perform()` method, which calls its internal `Actor`'s `perform()` method. In this case, it will take the one whose priority is `URGENT`, which happens to run the function `returnThree()`.

So this will do what you asked for. And yet I recommend against it. It can only perform functions that have no parameters (or just call a specific function with predetermined parameters). You can't pass it something like `Math.sqrt`, because when you need to perform it, there is no way for you to pass a number to that function.

What this leads to is using global-scope fields to pass data to the various functions instead of parameters. This in turn leads to readability issues, lack of encapsulation, which means your parameters may be changed by methods you didn't intend to change them. It's all sorts of bad. In addition, in this particular setting, how will you know which parameters to set in the global scope if you don't know which function you're going to run next?